# "Mean-field results" in Probability theory

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

I'm studying a paper on (biological) Neural Networks, and the paper studies some stability properties of an $N$-sized network, and then, as $N$ tends to infinity, it is proven that a "mean-field result holds".

Now, I've already read the Wikipedia article about "mean-field Theory" and besides the concept of "averaging" the effect of many particles into 1 averaged-effect; I don't see any other similarity: In this paper there's no Hamiltonian.

So I would like what is exactly understood by "Mean-Field Theory" in the context of Probability theory. Is there any bibliography introducing this topic?

Thank you!

Comment: truly recommend https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/07/mean-field-equations/